# Bootstrap 4 column classes don't work properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alpha, grid-system

I know that bootstrap 4 is in alpha, but for me grid system is not working.
I have

```
<row> 
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
</row>
```

And even for 360x512 its always showing up like for big devices. Same problem ive got with visibility.

Comment: A functional example of the code you are using that illustrates the problem would be best here.

Comment: You should post your code on JSFiddle. So we can see your problem clearly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/58/

Comment: I mean that col-md-* is not working and there are two sizes: big( >1000px) and small (100px>)

Comment: and medium size should be from 768 px nd there is nothing, on 768px is still sm class
http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/59/